Program closes before function returns to main. Exception thrown: read access violation. **_Val** was 0x19B6C345688
My displayRecord() function runs correctly. It will display the given record, then pause for a second, but then the program closes before the function returns to main().
After debugging, I received this error:

Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Val was 0x19B6C345688.

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    string description;
    int quantity;
    double wCost;
    double rCost;
    string dateAdded;
};

int addRecord();
int displayRecord();
int changeRecord();

int main()
{  
    cout << "Inventory Program" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl << endl;

    char again = 'y';
    int selection = 0;

    do 
    {
        cout << "MENU" << endl;
        cout << "----" << endl;
        cout << "1. Add a record" << endl;
        cout << "2. Display a record" << endl;
        cout << "3. Change a record" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit Program" << endl << endl;

        do
        {
            cout << "Please enter a selection from the menu (1, 2, 3, or 4): ";
            cin >> selection;

            if (selection != 1 && selection != 2 && selection != 3 && selection != 4)
            {
                cout << "\nYou must enter a valid selection of either 1, 2, 3, or 4. Please try again.\n\n";
                
            }

        } while (selection != 1 && selection != 2 && selection != 3 && selection != 4);

        if (selection == 4)
        {
            cout << "Exiting Program..." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            return 0;
        }

        if (selection == 1)
        {   
            if (addRecord() == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        else if (selection == 2)
        {
            if (displayRecord() == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if (changeRecord() == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        cout << "Return to menu? (Type Y for yes): ";
        cin >> again;

    } while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y');
    

    cout << "-------------------------------" << endl << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}

int displayRecord()
{
    fstream inventoryFile("inventory.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!inventoryFile)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file. Aborting Program." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    Item item;
    long recNum = 0;
    
    cout << "\nEnter the record number you wish to display: ";
    cin >> recNum;

    inventoryFile.seekg((recNum - 1) * sizeof(item), ios::beg);
    inventoryFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item), sizeof(item));
    
    if (!inventoryFile)
    {
        cout << "\nERROR: Record does not exist." << endl << endl;
        inventoryFile.close();
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << showpoint << setprecision(2) << fixed << endl;
        cout << "Item Description: " << item.description << endl;
        cout << "Quantity        : " << item.quantity << endl;
        cout << "Wholesale Cost  : " << item.wCost << endl;
        cout << "Retail Cost     : " << item.rCost << endl;
        cout << "Date Added:     : " << item.dateAdded << endl << endl;
        inventoryFile.clear();
    }
                  
    inventoryFile.close();

    return 0;
}

I have another branch where I open the file in main() and pass the file to the function, but the same thing happens.
I have used clear() and seekg() to set the position at the beginning of the file.

We can't reproduce the issue since we can't link this. changeRecord() is missing for example

You can't store std::strings in binary files like that. A (long) std::string uses a pointer that points to the actual string data. That pointer will not be valid when you restart the program and read it from the file.

I have a feeling that both "address sanitizer" (asan) and "undefined behaviour sanitizer" (Busan) should be able to point you at your error - maybe even some extra compiler warnings. Have you tried those to get a clue?

My displayRecord() function runs correctly -- No it doesn't "run correctly".  inventoryFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item), sizeof(item)); -- There is no need to go further.  As mentioned, you cannot read a blob of bytes into a type that is non-trivial.  Your Item struct contains std::string members, and by reading into the Item objects by blasting bytes into it corrupts the object.

Storing data correctly into binary files is a very hard problem to solve in C++ even if you know what you are doing (it just depends on too many details).  You might want to read this : Iso C++ serialization and unserialization. That's why most programmers either use json, xml, yaml or another text format (and still use a library, like nlohman-json) or for binary serialization they use libraries like protobuf or flatbuffers. So reading binary data like this : (Item*)(&buffer[offset]) is NOT going to work!

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Your Item type is non-trivial, as it contains non-trivial std::string members. As such, you cannot use istream::read() and ostream::write() to read/write Item objects in binary mode the way you are doing.
std::string contains a pointer to its character data, which may be (and usually is) located elsewhere in memory, outside of the std::string object. You are reading/writing the internal state of the std::string objects, not their character data. So, when you write a file, then restart the program, and then read the file, you will not end up with valid string objects.
To read/write your items in binary mode, they need to be of a trivial type.  And to facilitate the random seeking that your code is using, those items need to be a fixed size. Which means, you will have to use fixed-length char[] arrays for your strings, eg:
struct Item
{
    char description[256];
    int quantity;
    double wCost;
    double rCost;
    char dateAdded[32];
};

Otherwise, if you want to read/write std::string values then you must (de-)serialize the Item objects instead (which is not kind to random seeking), eg:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    string description;
    int quantity;
    double wCost;
    double rCost;
    string dateAdded;
};

template<typename T>
istream& read(istream &in, T &value)
{
    return in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
}

template<typename T>
ostream& write(ostream &out, const T &value)
{
    return out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
}

istream& read(istream &in, string &value)
{
    uint32_t size;
    if (in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size)))
    {
        value.resize(size);
        in.read(value.data(), size);
    }
    return in;
}

ostream& write(ostream &out, const string &value)
{
    uint32_t size = value.size();
    if (out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size)))
        out.write(value.c_str(), size);
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream &in, Item &item)
{
    read(in, item.description);
    read(in, item.quantity);
    read(in, item.wCost);
    read(in, item.rCost);
    read(in, item.dateAdded);
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Item &item)
{
    write(out, item.description);
    write(out, item.quantity);
    write(out, item.wCost);
    write(out, item.rCost);
    write(out, item.dateAdded);
    return out;
}

...

int addRecord()
{
    Item item;
    ...

    ofstream inventoryFile("inventory.dat", ios::binary | ios::app);
    if (!inventoryFile)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file. Aborting Program." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(inventoryFile << item))
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot write to file. Aborting Program." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int displayRecord()
{
    ifstream inventoryFile("inventory.dat", ios::binary);
    if (!inventoryFile)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file. Aborting Program." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    long recNum = 0;
    
    cout << "\nEnter the record number you wish to display: ";
    cin >> recNum;

    Item item;
    while (recNum > 1)
    {
        if (!(inventoryFile >> item))
        {
            cout << "\nERROR: Record does not exist." << endl << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        ---recNum;
    }
    
    if (!(inventoryFile >> item))
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot read from file. Aborting Program." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << showpoint << setprecision(2) << fixed << endl;
    cout << "Item Description: " << item.description << endl;
    cout << "Quantity        : " << item.quantity << endl;
    cout << "Wholesale Cost  : " << item.wCost << endl;
    cout << "Retail Cost     : " << item.rCost << endl;
    cout << "Date Added:     : " << item.dateAdded << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}

int changeRecord()
{
    ifstream inventoryFile("inventory.dat", ios::binary);
    if (!inventoryFile)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open file. Aborting Program." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ofstream inventoryTemp("inventory.tmp", ios::binary);
    if (!inventoryTemp)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot create file. Aborting Program." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    long recNum = 0;
    
    cout << "\nEnter the record number you wish to change: ";
    cin >> recNum;

    Item item;
    while (recNum > 1)
    {
        if (!(inventoryFile >> item))
        {
            cout << "\nERROR: Record does not exist." << endl << endl;
            inventoryTemp.close();
            remove("inventory.tmp");
            return 0;
        }
        if (!(inventoryTemp << item))
        {
            cout << "ERROR: Cannot write to file. Aborting Program." << endl;
            inventoryTemp.close();
            remove("inventory.tmp");
            return 1;
        }
        ---recNum;
    }
    
    if (!(inventoryFile >> item))
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot read from file. Aborting Program." << endl;
        inventoryTemp.close();
        remove("inventory.tmp");
        return 1;
    }

    // display item...
    // ask user for new values...

    if (!(inventoryTemp << item))
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot write to file. Aborting Program." << endl;
        inventoryTemp.close();
        remove("inventory.tmp");
        return 1;
    };

    while (inventoryFile >> item)
    {
        if (!(inventoryTemp << item))
        {
            cout << "ERROR: Cannot write to file. Aborting Program." << endl;
            inventoryTemp.close();
            remove("inventory.tmp");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    if (!inventoryFile.eof())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot read from file. Aborting Program." << endl;
        inventoryTemp.close();
        remove("inventory.tmp");
        return 1;
    }

    inventoryFile.close();
    inventoryTemp.close();

    remove("inventory.bak");
    rename("inventory.dat", "inventory.bak");
    rename("inventory.tmp", "inventory.dat");

    return 0;
}

